# IIS not working win 7 home basic

Tags: iis

I m using windows 7 home basic in which iis all features are not supported so is there any alternate solution to get iis server without changing my os version?

Answer (score 0):

To enable IIS feature :

1. Click **Start** and then click **Control Panel**.
2. In Control Panel, click Programs and then click **Turn Windows features on or off**.
3. In the Windows Features dialog box, click **Internet Information Services** and then click OK.